# How to copy entire xml(<any type>) to a single node using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, biztalk

I will have to receive a XML message (of type xmlDocument) and copy the entire xml content to a single node of another strongly typed xml message.

I created a generic schema as below and used it in Map to transform it but I am unable to do it as the MessageType (Namespace#RootNode) is unknown.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003">
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:complexContent mixed="true">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:anyType"/>
      </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Huh? What does XSD have to do with XSLT? But for copying a full node tree, google "XSLT identity transform".

Comment: Key words to look at, Envelope Schema.  Have you tried setting the schema you have above as the Envelope schema and the payload on a XML Assembler in the pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

You can use xpath function inside your orchestration.

1) Get the content of the source XML in an System.Xml.XmlElement variable (Variable_1):

```
Variable_1 = xpath(Message_1, "/");
```

2) Init the destination message with a Message Assignement shape:

```
xmlDocument = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.LoadXml("<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0='http://BizTalkMassCopy.Schema1'><Field>Field_0</Field><MyRecord></MyRecord></ns0:Root>");
Message_2 = xmlDocument;
```

3) In the same shape, assign with xpath function the XmlElement, in my case the destination node is 'MyRecord':

```
xpath(Message_2, "/*[local-name()='Root' and namespace-uri()='http://BizTalkMassCopy.Schema1']/*[local-name()='MyRecord' and namespace-uri()='']") = Variable_1;
```